# How can I create vector illustration of mathematical and organic chemical formulas?

Tags: vector, mac

I am using Macbook Air, OS X 10.9.2. I want to create vector illustration of mathematical and organic formulas, so I can use those vector illustrations for T-shirts.

Examples:

[image]
[image]

How can I do that on Macbook Air? I am now studying Lynda.com-Illustrator CS6 One-on-One Fundamentals, but that does not help so much.

Comment: For the formulas you can use [Latexit](http://www.chachatelier.fr/latexit/) which can generate the formula in eps format. The eps can be pasted and scaled in Illustrator. The chemical structural formula can be made as Scott explains.

Answer (score 8):

For the mathematical formulas, I would definitely use LaTeX, since it gives you high quality typesetting for math stuff. You don't have to install LaTeX yourself if you don't want to, because there are online LaTeX renderers which let you export the result to e.g. pdf.

Therefore, if you go to [this site](http://www.tlhiv.org/ltxpreview/) and enter the correct code for your formula

```
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\int_0^1\dots\int_0^1\
    cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}(x_1+x_2+\ldots x_n)\right) dx_1 dx_2\ldots dx_n$$
```

you can download it as pdf which can be directly used in Illustrator.

The chemical formulas are a bit harder, because I haven't found any online editors which give you vector graphics, but I'm sure that there are free programs you can install which do that. Before you go this way, you should carefully check whether the structural formula you want isn't something which can be found [in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caffeine) or in another database. There, you might find a svn/eps/pdf file of the structure.

> [image]

Comment: +1 for using LaTeX. There are packages for drawing chemical formulae in LaTeX as well, such as `mhchem`.

Comment: @alexwlchan I wasn't sure about the experience of the OP with LaTeX. I used OChem once and I guess when you haven't used LaTeX much, trying to typeset chemical structures will end in suicide (same is true for MusicTeX btw).

Comment: @alexwlchan [`mhchem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) is for TYPING chemical formulas, whereas [`chemfig`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemfig) is for DRAWING.

Answer (score 3):

You can write your formulae in Illustrator. Then you can go Type -> outline. That will make your text vector, and you can scale as much as you want.

To write formulae in an efficient way in Illustrator, you need a plugin, or you can combine Illustrator and LaTex. To compose them of the separate elements are not really very efficient. I have not done this myself, but a quick search brings up a few option (I would have included them here, but my net is snailpace :S)

Comment: Sir, the question is I don't know how to write formulas in Illustrator.

Comment: Google "type tutorial illustrator"

Answer (score 2):

Use the Type tool to set the formulas. You might want to explore the **Glyph Panel** to find some of the operators. Simply click with the type tool and start typing.

You can then use the **Line Tool** to draw the lines.

When you have everything in the document, you can then use the **Move Tool** (the black arrow) to move things into whatever position you desire.

The fact that you have a Mackbook Air is largely irrelevant. Illustrator is Illustrator regardless of platform. The steps you need to accomplish this image are very basic operations with the type, line, and Move tools. If you have a Lynda.com subscription you simply need to review the core basics of those three tools to accomplish your image. THere's nothing fancy or tricky about it.